# How to make add to cart without reloading the page (js and django)?

Tags: javascript, django

Im making this add to cart functionality, and I want to show the new cart total after adding to cart without reloading the page. Right now I have it to reload the page to show the cart changes after having added a product.

(SOME OF THE CODE CAN BE IN DANISH, I HOPE ITS FINE)

HTML (The add to cart button)

```
<div class="buy-item flex flex-ai-c">
            <button data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add" class="add-button add-btn update-cart">TILFØJ TIL KURV</button>
            <div class="flex flex-ai-c flex-jc-c">
                <span class="cart-quantity-text">ANTAL</span>
                <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
function addCookieItem(productId, action) {

if(action == 'add'){
    if(cart[productId] == undefined){
        cart[productId] = {'quantity':parseInt(antal.value)}
    }else{
        cart[productId]['quantity'] += parseInt(antal.value)
    }
}

if(action == 'add-from-cart'){
        cart[productId]['quantity'] += 1
}

if(action == 'remove-from-cart'){
    cart[productId]['quantity'] -= 1

    if(cart[productId]['quantity'] <= 0){
        console.log('Remove Item')
        delete cart[productId]
    }
}

if(action == 'delete'){
    delete cart[productId]
}
console.log('Cart:', cart)
document.cookie = 'cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/"
location.reload()
}
```

Django

```
def cookieCart(request):

try:
    cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])
except:
    cart = {}

print('Cart:', cart)
items = []
order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

for i in cart:
    try:
        cartItems += cart[i]['quantity']

        product = Product.objects.get(id=i)
        total = (product.price * cart[i]['quantity'])

        order['get_cart_total'] += total
        order['get_cart_items'] += cart[i]['quantity']

        item = {
            'product':{
                'id':product.id,
                'name':product.name,
                'price':product.price,
                'imageURL': product.imageURL,
                'stripe-price': product.stripe_price_id,
                'description': product.description,
                'vare_nr': product.vare_nr,
            },
            'quantity': cart[i]['quantity'],
            'get_total': total
        }
        items.append(item)

    except:
        pass
return {'cartItems': cartItems, 'order': order, 'items':items}

def cartData(request):

cookieData = cookieCart(request)
cartItems = cookieData['cartItems']
order = cookieData['order']
items = cookieData['items']


return {'cartItems': cartItems, 'order': order, 'items':items}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with (very) different approaches:

1. using an Ajax call (XMLHttpRequest) with [vanilla javascript code](http://vanilla-js.com/)
2. using [HTMX](https://htmx.org/docs/) - quite new and less traditional way to boost your templating capabilities without writing JS code.
3. using a JS Frontend framework/library (React, Vue, Angular, Svelte, etc..)

there are other methods offcourse but i think that for Django, those will be the main ones and the most documented solutions.

Comment: JQuery, HTMX, and all the other JS frameworks are all using the same old Javascript `XMLHttpRequest`, so why not proposing the Javascript solution first? http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: @E-telier what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that the answer of rotcoil is on the right track but incomplete. What you need is indeed AJAX, but you don't need any fancy framework or library for that. Have a look at the http://vanilla-js.com/ website, you'll find an example under the title "Make an AJAX call".

Comment: @E-telier, you are right, i've edit my comment, thanks.